# Multithreading Query Code Throwing Null Exception

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Whats wrong with the below code? I have very little experience with threading, my limited understanding based on an msdn tutorial I may have misinterpreted is that the t1 and t2 declarations, the address of bits, I would be able to run the methods multithreaded (is that the best way to do it?)

And this isn't working. Previous the code worked fine for the methods that are there. The error flagged is

> system null exception, value can't be zero...

Oh also, it's reading a .txt so don't worry about that being thread unsafe stuff I don't think.

```
Private Sub Rreader(path As String)
  Dim reader1 As New RReaderClass       
  Dim t1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf reader1.stage1)     
  Dim t2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf reader1.stage2)
  Try
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.toString)
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub stage1()
  Try
    a()
    b()
    c()
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.toString)
  End Try
End Sub

Private Sub stage2()
  ….
```

Comment: Which line do you get the null reference exception on?  are you sure the error isn't inside the a, b or c methods for which you haven't provided code?

Comment: Yep, I now think it is (did a little test), apologies my first thought was the thread stuff because i have no experience there. But that code worked fine previously? all i've done is try and multithread it and split into two methods? All those methods contain is some basic linq. But yeah null value thing seems to be coming from the method ... :-S

Comment: Very embarrassing this. Apologies forget i was here...

Comment: Creating the separate method lost the visibility of a variable that messed the whole thing up. Thanks for your help anyway James.

Comment: Nope I'm wrong. All fine. If I run the method outside the threads it works fine. If within it doesn't work? What would explain that?

Comment: Please create a reduced test case for your problem. Something that you can publish here and we can reproduce. Ideally, create a new project and paste the relevant parts. If special project settings are required, please include those as well.

Comment: Can you show all the code including a, b, c methods?  And detail the line which raises the exception?

Comment: Would you expect that error with a deadlock issue? All a, b, c methods do is read a text file and use linq to drill for data. Happy to provide a test case, but I think I may know what it is, is that error what you'd see if the thread tried to read the file but couldn't because it was busy? Thats the only difference i think. 

Does a text file need to be thread safe? (as I've assumed it doesn't). And one thing I've noticed this is a .deb log, does that have to be thread safe?

Comment: The methods are all identical, aside from the query they're looking for. Like - 

Private Sub a()

        Dim result = From vr1 In arrLines
                      Where (vr1.Contains("33129”)
                      Select vr1

      

 If result.LongCount > 500 Then
            MessageBox.Show(“Too big”)

            Return
        End If

        For Each i In result
            txtFound.Text &= i & vbNewLine              'note &=

        Next
End Sub

Comment: Think it was due to - Dim reader1 As New RReaderClass. Not having a variable declared but now i've hit a different problem.. Thanks for your help guys!